# Julia. Relabelling a vector

Tags: vector, indexing, wolfram-mathematica, julia

I have a vector of non-consecutive integers that I need to use as indices for a matrix. In order to create a matrix of minimal size, I want to relabel the entries of the vector in the following way:

```
input = [794, 421, 496, 158, 421, 794, 794, 656, 108, 496, 496, 687, 108, 511, 108, 108, 158, 687, 158, 687]
output = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 6, 3, 3, 7, 6, 8, 6, 6, 4, 7, 4, 7]
```

Here is an example of how I do that in Mathematica:

```
labels = DeleteDuplicates[input]
output = Flatten[Position[labels, #] & /@ input]
```

What is and efficient way to do this in Julia?

Thanks,
Keyan

Comment: Take a look at [`unique`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.unique) and [`indexin`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.indexin).

Comment: Just have, and found the solution: relabel(v::Vector{Int64}) = findin(v, unique(v)). Thanks

Comment: actually, a bug/misdescription of findin makes this solution temporarily problematic. use `indexin` instead.

Comment: Since you found the answer yourself it is custom on SO to add an answer yourself. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: Thanks for the advance, and you are correct. findin is a bug

Answer (score 2):

The solution is

```
relabel(v::Vector{Int64}) = indexin(v, unique(v))
```